# Pointers with character array variables

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C++ and was understanding pointers and created the following code

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[100] = "Today is a rainy day";
    cout<<s[0]<<endl;
    char *p;
    p = s;
    cout <<s<<endl;
    cout<<p<<endl;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
}
```

In this code, I assumed that as s points to the starting address of the array, printing the pointer p will give me the address and *p will give me the first element of the array.

My output was of the form

```
T
Today is a rainy day
Today is a rainy day
T
```

Here, p and s both print out the complete character array which I did not understand, also using the *p was printing out the first element even though p was now just an array.

How do the pointers function when we use them in arrays like this is what I would like to understand.

Comment: Pointer is just a memory address value (i.e. unsigned long long). `*p` is accesing a memory on address it points, same as `s[0]`. ++p or --p moving pointer to next or previews memory address according to data type size. In case of char one byte forward or backward.

Comment: `s` is an array, it's not a pointer to the first element of the array, and `p` is pointer, not an array. The obvious things are true. What you are getting confused about is that in some circumstances `s` can be interpretted as a pointer to the first element of the array, but that doesn't change the fact that `s` is an array, always.

Comment: When does the array point to the first element and when does it behave like the whole string like here

Comment: @shawnindamnen When you use the array name in almost any expression it gets interpretted as a pointer (the important exception is when it's used in a `sizeof` expression). And when you pass a char* pointer to cout (`cout << s`) cout uses that pointer to print the whole string. That's just the way that `cout <<` has been written. It's a special case.

Comment: @shawnindamnen If you try a different kind of array (say an `int` array) you'll find that cout does not print the whole array. As I said char pointers and cout are a special case.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a pointer and an array exists only at compile time.
At runtime they are the same, decayed to pointers.

For an array at compile time you can find its dimensions, and use those as parameters in template code. See [`std::is_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array), [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent), etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you dereference either the array or pointer, you end up with a `char`. This prints that `char`, as you might have expected.

However, when you provide a `char*` (which is what you get with both the array and pointer case, as the array decays to a pointer here), the overload of the `operator<<` for `char*` is called instead.

This overload treats any `char*` it sees as a C-string, which is why you see it printed out as such.